# Itinerate over json with keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having troubles itinerating on a json, it looks like this:

```
{
"name":"Meeting 2021",
"translate": {"de":okay","fr":"okay2"}
}
```

I'm trying create a for on the translate key.

I tried the following but I end up splitting the strings letter by letter:

```
 var arr = JSON.parse(responsex.translate);

    arr.forEach(function (elementObject) {
        var keys = Object.keys(elementObject);
        keys.forEach(function (key) {
        console.log(key + ':' + elementObject[key]);
         })
   });
```

I also tried doing a simple for but I'm getting undefined index. What exactly am I doing wrong?
I'm simply trying to get the DE and FR values individually so I can make a simple html select.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use `for (let item of items) {...}` instead of the "old school" method. It is easyer to work with IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you're attempting to loop through an object as if it's an array. The two are not analogous data structures.

Instead you can use `Object.keys()` to get the keys from the `translate` property, then loop through them:

```js
let obj = {
  "name": "Meeting 2021",
  "translate": {
    "de": "okay",
    "fr": "okay2"
  }
}

Object.keys(obj.translate).forEach(k => {
  console.log(`${k}: ${obj.translate[k]}`);
});
```

Assuming you don't need IE support you can use the more modern `Object.entries()` method:

```js
let obj = {
  "name": "Meeting 2021",
  "translate": {
    "de": "okay",
    "fr": "okay2"
  }
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj.translate)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```